# How to remove variables which are too similar in R?

Tags: r, variables

I have around 50 variables, with about 200 observations in R. Some variables are very similar to others, sharing almost all values. This is causing issues with some models. How can I remove variables which share, say 90%, of the values? I can't think of an efficient way to do this without checking all pairwise combinations.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One way is to get the frequency table on each of those columns, get the proportions and create a condition with `max` with respect to 0.90

```
Filter(function(x) {
      x1 <- table(x)
      max(proportions(x1)) < .90}, df1)
```

---

A reproducible example with `mtcars`

```
> data(mtcars)
> nrow(mtcars)
[1] 32
> 32 * 0.9
[1] 28.8

> mtcars$new <- rep(c(1, 2), c(29, 3))
> Filter(function(x) {
+       x1 <- table(x)
+       max(proportions(x1)) < .90}, mtcars)
                     mpg cyl  disp  hp drat    wt  qsec vs am gear carb
Mazda RX4           21.0   6 160.0 110 3.90 2.620 16.46  0  1    4    4
Mazda RX4 Wag       21.0   6 160.0 110 3.90 2.875 17.02  0  1    4    4 
...
```